# Excel add one hour

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I have in cel A1 with the following contents:

`7:30:43` 
which is a time.

But now i want to use a formula to add one hour. What is the best way or how can i do this?

Comment: As a financial developer who produces solutions mixing VBA, .NET VSTO and Excel worksheet functions, this is most certainly not off topic.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
=A1+TIME(1,0,0)
```

Although, maybe this should be posted on Super User.

Comment: You can always just use =A1 + 1/24

Comment: Similiar Posting on Super User @http://superuser.com/questions/194302/how-to-add-80000-hours-to-all-the-datetime-values-in-a-column-in-ms-excel-shee

Answer (score 14):

In cell A1, enter the time.
In cell B2, enter `=A1+1/24`

Answer (score 0):

This may help you as well.  This is a conditional statement that will fill the cell with a default date if it is empty but will subtract one hour if it is a valid date/time and put it into the cell.

```
=IF((Sheet1!C4)="",DATE(1999,1,1),Sheet1!C4-TIME(1,0,0))
```

You can also substitute `TIME` with `DATE` to add or subtract a date or time.